# function decorator reassigning hoisted inner function without eval

Tags: javascript, eval, decorator, hoisting

I'm playing about with [function decorators](https://github.com/raganwald/method-combinators/blob/master/README-JS.md). I'd like to have a way to easily decorate functions **without having to do it where the function is declared**.

```
var __slice = [].slice;

  this.around = function(decoration) {
    return function(base) {
      return function() {
        var argv, callback, __value__,
          _this = this;
        argv = 1 <= arguments.length ? __slice.call(arguments, 0) : [];
        __value__ = void 0;
        callback = function() {
          return __value__ = base.apply(_this, argv);
        };
        decoration.apply(this, [callback].concat(argv));
        return __value__;
      };
    };
  };

f("from outer");
function f(a){
  console.log("f OUTER",a);
};
f("from outer");
(function g(){
  f("from Inner (hoisted)");


function addDecorator(decoration, fn) {
  var decorated = around(decoration)(fn);
  eval(fn.name + " = decorated");
  decorated.unDecorate = function (){
    eval(fn.name + " = fn");
  }
}

  function myDecorator(cb){
      console.log("before");
      cb();
      console.log("after");
    }


  function f(a){
    console.log("f INNER",a);
  }

  f("from Inner (after declaration)");
  addDecorator(myDecorator, f);

  f("from Inner (Decorated)");
  f.unDecorate();
  f("from Inner (Undecorated)");
})();
f("from outer");
```

I want to be able to call `addDecorator` anywhere inside `g`. i.e. at the top where `f` is hoisted above it's declaration.

In Chrome's console I get the following output:

```
f OUTER from outer
f OUTER from outer
f INNER from Inner (hoisted)
f INNER from Inner (after declaration)
before
f INNER from Inner (Decorated)
after
f INNER from Inner (Undecorated)
f OUTER from outer
```

1. Can this be done without eval?
2. Can addDecorator be moved outside g? (not as important)

Comment: I don't quite get what you are asking, but if the main question is - Can I invoke decorated `f` in top of `g` before decoration was applied to `f` - my answer is no. Hoisting brings up function bodies for use higher in code than those functions where assigned, but decoration is an Operation not a Declaration, so it will happen only at it's moment in runtime sequence.

Comment: No, the question is not about that. It's a very interesting way of redefining functions - and it seems that answers for both questions are 'no', actually. Still investigating, though. )

Comment: @Brock, f is hoisted to top of g, decoration is added to g, then f is declared. I didn't expect to be able to call decorated f before calling the decorator function.

Comment: I'll accept answers that change how `g` is structured or called as long as `addDecorator` can be made aware of where the function passed in is defined so it doesn't have to return the decorated function to be assigned to the original function's name. i.e. I don't want to have code like `f = addDecorator(d,f)`, so I can make a varadic version: `addDecorationXxToAllOf(f1, f2, f3)`

Comment: the `instrumentFunction` here looks interesting: https://github.com/stacktracejs/stacktrace.js/blob/master/stacktrace.js

Comment: @SamHasler: The answer is definitely "no" on both questions. Unlike with global scope, JavaScript explicitly doesn't give you a way to access function scope in some generic way. So you can either return the new function value or use an object to store the functions. Note that `instrumentFunction` above also works for global functions only where the scope can be accessed.

Comment: @WladimirPalant Thanks, that's what I thought. I wanted to make sure there wasn't something I'd overlooked.

Answer (score 2):

You can both eliminate `eval` and move the function outside of `g` if you are willing to change your convention slightly.

This will have the same effect but is called slightly differently:

```
function addDecorator(decoration, fn) {
    var decorated = around(decoration)(fn);
    decorated.unDecorate = function () {
        return fn;
    }
    return decorated;
}

f = addDecorator(myDecorator, f);

f = f.unDecorate();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8SuT9/1/

If you aren't willing to change the way it is called/used then I'm afraid the answer to both of your questions is no.

Comment: I think I'd be more willing to put all my functions inside an object so that I could curry passing the object to addDecorator to avoid having to do the assignment.

Comment: @SamHasler Also doable.  One way or another though I believe you'll have to change your approach to achieve the removal of `eval`.